# Gradle product flavor in "pure" gradle (not android gradle)

Tags: java, gradle

I want to build a java library for different customers with gradle. 
Is there something like product flavors known from android in "pure" gradle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes but you will have to use the new Gradle software model which is very much incubating. It will be a road full of pain as you will be a trail blazer as I have learned using it for a C/Cpp project. Here is generally how your build will look like.

```
plugins {
    id 'jvm-component'
    id 'java-lang'
}

model {
  buildTypes {
    debug
    release
  }
  flavors {
    free
    paid
  }
    components {
        server(JvmLibrarySpec) {
            sources {
                java {
                  if (flavor == flavors.paid) {
                    // do something to your sources
                  }
                  if (builtType == buildTypes.debug) {
                    // do something for debuging
                  }
                    dependencies {
                        library 'core'
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        core(JvmLibrarySpec) {
            dependencies {
                library 'commons'
            }
        }

        commons(JvmLibrarySpec) {
            api {
                dependencies {
                    library 'collections'
                }
            }
        }

        collections(JvmLibrarySpec)
    }
}
```

References:
1) Java Software Model https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_software.html
2) Flavors https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/native_software.html
note: I'm not sure how well flavors are supported the Java Software Model, I will do some testing and report back.

Update: It is doable but is not currently supported by the JvmLibrarySpec. I will try to post a more complete answer with an example of how to do the custom spec.

Comment: @RaGe I updated the references. I need to do some double checking to make sure it works as noted. I work with the software model exclusively in c/cpp and not in our Android/Java Projects. Let me do some test and I'll report back.

Comment: @RaGe it is doable but is not currently supported by the JvmLibrarySpec. To do it you will have to create you own spec. I'll try to post an example tomorrow.

Comment: @MichaelHobbs: Do you have a complete minimal example for that?